# Integrate react app with uwp app

Tags: reactjs, uwp

I would like to integrate react app in uwp app
I have the access to react app build directory and I want to show the content of index.html of react inside webview of uwp app.

my code looks like snippet below, but it is not working.

```
ReactWebView.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appx-web:///Models/test-app/build/index.html"));
```

uwp app just show blank page .it does not show any content

Comment: How is not working? What error message are you receiving? You'll need to provide more details in order to get an accurate answer.

Comment: it just show blank page ,no content

Comment: If your app is this [react app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#creating-an-app), so it is a node.js web app whose code can not run in UWP app directly. You can try the [Hosted Web Apps](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/hosted-web-apps).

Comment: after changing relative path in index.html to app specific path ,my code worked                                                                                           </head>
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ms-appx-web:///Models/test-app/build/static/js/main.a3b22bcc.js">
    </script>
    </body>

Comment: Hi, I am currently also trying to add react to my uwp app and I have trouble integrating them. Could you please show me more code about your solution or maybe a working example? Thank you!